# Android Layout not changing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I created a simple layout and called it activity_main.xml this layout is for device 3.4 inch. I then created a new layout file in a folder in eclipse and added a screen configuration of large screen setting the size to x-large this is for 10.1 inch. I then deleted the xml file in this folder and copy pasted the activity_main.xml file into this folder. I then changed the size of the text and images to cater for large screen. So now both files are called activity_main.xml. However the problem is that when I run the emulator for the big screen it still only displays the content using the layout created for 3.4 inch screen.

Can anybody help me with this? Why is that?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Answer (score 0):

You should put each layout to its folder :)
this link will help you :)

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

this is a sample app : 
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

i hope this will help you :)

Comment: it is in the folder so the 3.4 inch layout is in a folder called layout and the 10.1 inch layout is in a folder called layout-large